# PPL - license and link information

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing, ppl

I would like to use PPL with compiler VS2010. what is license status for PPL? can it be freely used in commercial software, and can you point at the relevant doc? How is it bound for appropriate compilation or how does it work? Do I have to download a separate library, or tick an option for compiler... ?

thanks and regards

Comment: It is part of the Microsoft libraries, which makes it almost guaranteed that it will be useable in proprietary software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx) is built into the Microsoft libraries, and included with VS 2010's compiler and library stack.  You can use it in commercial software under the same terms as the other MS libraries included with the compiler (see Redist.txt in the ..\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ folder for details).

> How is it bound for appropriate compilation or how does it work? 
>   In order to see how it works, see the [relevant documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx).

Comment: I wonder whether the two include `#include <ppl.h>`
`#include <concurrent_vector.h>` are asking for dll, and what these dl are? Same for `using namespace Concurrency;`

Comment: @dlib Its part of the normal MS VC++ runtimes